# Partial Fraction: Already irreducible?

Tags: partial-fractions

I have this partial fraction:
$${3x+7}\over{(x-4)^2+25}$$
As far as I can tell, I do not think this can be decomposed. Is that a correct assumption?

Sorry for the very short question, there isn't much work I could show, I think.

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, in $\mathbb{R}$ is this fraction irreducible.

Answer (score 2):

In case the purpose is to find an antiderivative

$$\frac{3x+7}{x^2-8x+41} = \frac{3x-12}{x^2-8x+41} + \frac{19}{x^2-8x+41} = \left( \frac{3}{2} \right)  \left( \frac{2x-8}{x^2-8x+41} \right) +  \left( \frac{19}{(x-4)^2+25} \right) $$

For the 19 part, we would expect to use a substitution $$ x-4 = 5 u $$